# viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear callbacks when a ViewController's view is hidden by another view & UIViewController Containment in iOS5

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios5

The [UIViewController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear%3a) mentions about `-viewWillDisappear:`

> "This method is called in response to a view being removed from its
>   window ***or covered by another view***. This method is called before
>   the view is actually removed or covered and before any animations are
>   configured."

In iOS 4.3 and lower we are supposed to present a viewController and not add a viewController's view to the view hierarchy explicitly, so the calls `-viewWillDisappear` or `-viewDidDisappear` would be triggered when a new view controller is being presented over the existing view, in which case '***covered by another view***' is true! But what if a viewController's view is hidden since another view obstructs the viewController's view? Do we get these callbacks?

Well, in iOS 5 there is a UIViewController containment concept where views can be directly added as subviews in view hierarchy by setting the parent-child relationship between viewControllers. So, unlike <= 4.3 OS, -`viewWillDisappear` and `-viewDidDisappear` calls should ideally be triggered when a viewController's view is obstructed or covered by some other view, which I have verified by a sample project that it is not happening in SDK 5.0.

Has anyone found this problem related to these callbacks?
Or, is my understanding correct?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

Someone has the same kind of problem here :

[iOS 5 : -viewWillAppear is not called after dismissing the modal in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802673/ios-5-viewwillappear-is-not-called-after-dismissing-the-modal-in-ipad)

You should read the answers, I found them very interesting.