# iOS 5 : -viewWillAppear is not called after dismissing the modal in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

I am presenting modal using the following code :

```
AddName *add = [[AddName alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddName" bundle:nil]
add.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalView:add animated:YES];
```

And After my work I use following code to go back on my main view.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So it use to call `-viewWillAppear` by default.

My problem is that,

It was working fine with **iOS4.3**.

But Its not working with **iOS5**.

What should I do ? Or Is that any bug in **iOS5**?

Comment: Is the problem that the -viewWillAppear is not called?  Or is it that the modal window isn't being presented?

Comment: @gaige: YES -viewWillAppear is not called

Comment: @Devang: Remove `add.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;` and it will call the viewWillAppear method. Please check about it.

Comment: @Parth Bhatt : But my code works fine with iOS4.3 but does not works for iOS 5.0. And I dont want to display whole screen.

Comment: I'd tag this "ios5-compatibility", but you can only have 5 tags.

Answer (score 11):

`-viewWillAppear` is only guaranteed to be called in places where the `-viewWillDisappear` has also been called.   For most modal windows on the iPad, this is not the case, since they don't obscure the entire page.

The solution to your problem will depend on what you need the `-viewWillAppear` for, but in general, you're likely to need to make a call directly from the same place that you dismiss the modal view controller.

One common mechanism for this, especially in cases where you might use that same modal view somewhere else, is to give the modal view controller a delegate which is called when the view is about to disappear.   This will give you a chance to take the responses from the modal window, or even just force a data reload in the delegate view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of a delegate in iOS5 you can try [[self presentingViewController] viewWillAppear:YES];

Comment: @NJones whereas it is true that you can call viewWillAppear: I would suggest it, as it has other side-effects (since the documentation notes that you MUST call super).

Comment: I assume you meant you wouldn't suggest it?

Comment: @gauge viewWillAppear would be called on the presenting view controller. If it wasn't overridden super would be called by default, if it was overridden then it's that classes responsibility to call [super viewWillAppear].

Comment: @NJones Yes, I did mean I would not suggest calling it.  In particular, the view itself on the iPad will not disappear, and therefore it is not re-appearing, it is merely having a part of it obscured and then displayed again.   By using viewWillAppear to signal the dismissal, you're basically overriding the viewWillAppear to take on a different meaning and since the OS performs certain functions during this call (due to the super implementation), you might see unexpected consequences.   In short, if what you want to know is that the modal disappeared, use a notification or delegate.  My $0.02

Comment: I agree. Delegation is preferred. Just saying it is possible solution. If I thought is was 'the' answer I would have made it an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 9):

iOS 5 definitely changed their calls to `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`.  For instance, subviews (`View Controller's views` as subviews to be exact) in a `UIScrollView`, `viewWillDisappear` will get called when you push another view controller onto the stack.  However, when the view controller is popped, `viewWillAppear` does not get called.  These methods were never called in iOS 4 on `UIScrollView` subviews.

This is strange behavior to me.  Couple that with the fact that regardless of what should happen, if you could rely on it happening in iOS 4, it should not be working differently in iOS 5.  Most of the time, I have no idea in which particular instance each one is called, I usually trial and error it as I'm in the zone coding.  If it works the way I like, I move on. Then iOS 5 comes in and throws a wrecking ball into everything.

I have also experienced when a `UINavigationController's` view is a subview, and a `ViewController` is pushed on the navigation controller stack, `viewWillAppear` never gets called in iOS 4, but does get called in iOS 5. Go figure.

Comment: And whoever down voted, please try this project with iOS 4 and iOS 5 simulator, and tell me you get the breakpoint in both sims... it's an NSLog statement in FirstViewController.m.    https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5DJHlwe-2MTYjY0ZDMyMzgtY2Q3Zi00NzRlLWEyYmQtMGY0YjgzMDNjZDdk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I found that `viewWillAppear` isn't get called after dismissing modal but `viewDidAppear` is. So just try `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: In the modal view I added `presentingViewController.viewDidAppear(true)` and then it worked but added the updateUI() (private func) call there.

Comment: it doesn't work. And it seems it has never been workable